# Como convertir array asociativo tipo object a array normal en laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo un **array asociativo** basado en un query builder de laravel el cual necesito convertir a **array normal**, cómo puedo concertirlo en array normal.

Array asociativo de tipo objeto basado en Query Builder:

```
$consulta = DB::table('partes_trabajo')

 ->select(
           'partes_trabajo.user_id as Usuario: ',
           DB::raw('SUM(desplazamiento) as Km'),
           DB::raw('SUM(peaje) as Peaje'),
           DB::raw('SUM(aparcamiento) as Aparcamiento'),
           DB::raw('SUM(otros_gastos) as Otros_gastos'),

                   )

  ->whereIn('user_id',$usuarios)
  ->whereBetween('fecha', [$fechaD, $fechaH])
  ->groupBy('user_id')
  ->get();
```

si hago un var_dump a $consulta, lo que me devuelve son estos objetos o array asociativo:

```
object(Illuminate\Support\Collection)#426 (1) { ["items":protected]=> array(3) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#424 (5) { ["Usuario: "]=> int(7) ["Km"]=> float(97.22) ["Peaje"]=> float(143) ["Aparcamiento"]=> float(8.2) ["Otros_gastos"]=> float(76.7) } [1]=> object(stdClass)#442 (5) { ["Usuario: "]=> int(10) ["Km"]=> float(54.15) ["Peaje"]=> float(0) ["Aparcamiento"]=> float(3.4) ["Otros_gastos"]=> float(70) } [2]=> object(stdClass)#425 (5) { ["Usuario: "]=> int(17) ["Km"]=> float(45.88) ["Peaje"]=> float(12.5) ["Aparcamiento"]=> float(0) ["Otros_gastos"]=> float(0) } } }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El método `get` de Query Builder, devuelve una Colección (`Illuminate\Support\Collection`) que contiene los resultados donde cada resultado es una instancia del objeto PHP `stdClass`, por lo que puedes usar sobre ella cualquiera de los [Métodos Disponibles](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#available-methods) para las colecciones.

Estos dos convierten una colección en un array:

#### [`toArray`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-toarray)

El método `toArray` convierte la colección en una matriz PHP simple.
*Nota*: `toArray` también convierte todos los objetos anidados de la colección en una matriz. Si desea obtener la matriz subyacente sin procesar, utilice el método `all` en su lugar.

```
$consulta->toArray();
```

#### [`all`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-all)

El método `all` devuelve la matriz subyacente representada por la colección.

```
$consulta->all();
```

Comment: Lo siento pero esto no me funciona he probrado con las dos formas y me sigue devolviendo lo mismo el var_dump.

Comment: disculpame funciona como tu has dicho a a las mil maravillas, ha sido error de mi caché ^^

Comment: @DavidRobles ten en cuenta que casi todos los métodos devuelven una nueva instancia de Colección, o en este caso un array, lo que le permite conservar la copia original de la colección. Por lo tanto si quieres el array en una variable debrás hacer `$array = $consulta->toArray();` o también puedes concatenarlo al get del final de tu consulta, y guardará el array en la variable `$consulta = DB::table('partes_trabajo') ... ->get()->toArray();`