# acceder a un valor de una collection

Tags: php, laravel

buenos días tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
      $dupplicate = DB::table('table')->whereIn('name', [$line])->select('name')->get();
```

arroja lo siguiente:

```
       Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1607 ▼
         #items: array:1 [▼
           0 => {#1610 ▼
            +"name": "20001"
           }
         ]
        #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
       }
```

valor de: $line[0] = "20001";

deseo obtener el valor únicamente de name, es decir obtener  "20001", ya que ese valor lo voy a usar para compararlo con $line, como no he podido tomar el dato "20001" nunca va a comparar, llevo toda la mañana intentando acceder, mucho sabría agradecer la ayuda que puedan brindarme

Comment: Puede que este post te ayude en lo que necesitas https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/332995/como-convertir-array-asociativo-tipo-object-a-array-normal-en-laravel

Comment: gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola si solo quieres un array con el valor de `name` te sirve esta forma

```
$dupplicate = DB::table('table')->whereIn('name', [$line])->select('name')->pluck('name');
```

lo que hace es obtener solo el valor de una columna, tus resultados quedaran asi

```
['20001', '20002', '20001']
```

o si quieres obtener dato a dato con el indice debes recorrer la coleccion, por ejemplo:

```
foreach($dupplicat as $dup){
  echo $dup->name
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias por la gran ayuda

Comment: es con mucho gusto :)